Make external monitor primary in Extend mode by default programmatically
When I connect an external monitor to my laptop and choose "Extend these displays," Windows chooses the small laptop monitor as the main display by default.
How can I make Windows default to the external monitor instead?
I know about MultiMonitorTool but am looking for a native programmatic solution that would work on a fresh install, such as a script, group policy or registry edit.
Switching to Extend mode seems easy enough by putting C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /extend in the startup dir, but making external monitors primary by default is proving to be difficult.

Are you aware that Windows has a primary display setting in display settings? There is no need for third-party software to set it.

I tried to find out where it saves to in the registry when setting it in the Windows Display Settings with Process Monitor, but wasn't successful.
